# Can't start MySQL after updating folder permission

Tags: linux, permissions, google-cloud

I accidentally set the permission of my folder to 755. After I restarted the server, I'm getting this error:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd (pid 2969) already running
file '/etc/gonit/gonitrc' must have permissions no more than -rwx------; right 
now permissions are -rwxrwxr-x.
```

I have executed the following commands to know the permission of the MySQL folders.

**command** : `ls -larth /etc/gonit/gonitrc`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mysql root 38 May 17 08:41 /etc/gonit/gonitrc -> /opt/bitnami/config/monit/bitnami.conf
```

**command** : `ls -larth /opt/bitnami/config/monit/bitnami.conf`

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mysql root 159 May 17 08:44 /opt/bitnami/config/monit/bitnami.conf
```

**command** : `ls -larth /opt/bitnami/mysql/`

```
total 6.7M
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql   root    2.5K Mar 18  2017 README
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql   root     18K Mar 18  2017 COPYING
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql   root    7.6M May 17 08:23 bnconfig
drwxr-xr-x 28 mysql   root    4.0K May 17 08:43 share
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql   root    4.0K May 17 08:43 scripts
drwxr-xr-x  3 mysql   root    4.0K May 17 08:43 include
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql   root    4.0K May 17 08:43 support-files
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql   root    4.0K May 17 08:43 bin
drwxr-xr-x  5 mysql   root    4.0K May 17 08:43 lib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql   root     572 May 17 08:47 my.cnf
drwx------ 15 bitnami bitnami 4.0K May 17 08:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql   root    4.0K Jun  1 11:04 bitnami
drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami daemon  4.0K Oct 18 01:06 tmp
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql   root       0 Oct 19 03:14 wrapper
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql   root       0 Oct 19 03:14 libmysqlclient.so.20.3.5
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql   root       0 Oct 19 03:14 libncurses.so.5
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql   root       0 Oct 19 03:14 libncurses.so.5.9
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql   root       0 Oct 19 03:14 libaio.so.1.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql   root       0 Oct 19 03:14 libmysqlclient.so.20
drwxr-xr-x 11 mysql   root    4.0K Oct 19 03:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 bitnami daemon  4.0K Oct 19 14:09 data
```

please advise if there the default permissions of each folder are correct? Thanks

Comment: Your title is asking about MySQL; your prose is talking about Apache.  Which is it?

Comment: chmod 700 /path/to/folder

Comment: @DopeGhoti it's when the mysql is starting using this command


     sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql

thanks

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal still not working. I can't access the folder right now after i run the command

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R username /path/to/folder`

Comment: Thank you @ArpitAgarwal. The MySql is now running but I receive the error that the directory must be owned by you.

    /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd (pid 2969) already running
file '/etc/gonit/gonitrc' must be owned by you.

Comment: Can you please attach the output in your post so that i can fix the issues and explain what's going on. Also attach the output of `ls -alh` in required directories

Comment: Hi @ArpitAgarwal, I have edited my post. i  have executed the following commands to know the permissions of the MySQL folder

`ls -larth /etc/gonit/gonitrc
ls -larth /opt/bitnami/config/monit/bitnami.conf
ls -larth /opt/bitnami/mysql/`

I don't know who should own  '/etc/gonit/gonitrc'. please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the output of `/opt/bitnami/mysql/`, all the folders and files are owned by group `mysql` and `root` user. You can add yourself to the `mysql` group

```
sudo useradd -G mysql username
```

Now, try running the it again, it still is gives warning then own these files by using `chown`

```
sudo chown -R username /etc/gonit/gonitrc
sudo chown -R username /opt/bitnami/config/monit/bitnami.conf
```

Let me know, if still it doesn't work.

You can use `docker` also for creating `mysql` server. It is easy to setup and manageable.

**Edit**

To change the permission of `/etc/gonit/gonitrc`

```
sudo chmod 700 /etc/gonit/gonitrc
```

To learn about `chmod` go to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_modes) page

Comment: Thank you Arpit. I encounter this problem:

`file '/etc/gonit/gonitrc' must have permissions no more than -rwx------; right now permissions are -rwxrwxr-x.`

I don't know the code for -rwx------ please advise. thanks

Comment: i have edited the answer now, let me know if it works

Comment: it still did not start. It says that the MySQL is Monitored. here's the output:
`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql
Unmonitored mysql
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql not running
2017-10-20T16:13:47.302915Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
2017-10-20T16:13:47.316872Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
2017-10-20T16:13:47.508942Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
Monitored mysql` 
thanks

Comment: Can you try to start `mysql` with `sudo`?

Comment: I tried this command `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql`
here's the result:
`2017-10-21T04:14:20.268547Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
2017-10-21T04:14:20.281813Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
2017-10-21T04:14:20.483984Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
Monitored mysql`